# Condition to COMPARE TWO DATE From parameter and ADD if it Satisfies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, procedure

This is MY procedure , Im getting **from** and to **date** in the procedure
i have to check if difference between FROM and TO date is greater than 2

if the condition satisfies  i have to add 2days in from days and set it as TODATE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TU_AvgStdDev_Report] 
@FromDate as Datetime,
@ToDate as Datetime,
@RecipeCode as Varchar(8000),
@Grade as Varchar(10),
@WcID as Int
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF (condition to check if @FromDate - @ToDate  > 2)
--if it satisfies
SET @ToDate to @fromDate+2Days
```

Please help me in figuring it out...

Comment: Can you please check the below solution and please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to used date functions for this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TU_AvgStdDev_Report] 
@FromDate as Datetime,
@ToDate as Datetime,
@RecipeCode as Varchar(8000),
@Grade as Varchar(10),
@WcID as Int
AS
BEGIN
IF (datediff(day,@FromDate,@ToDate)>2)
SET @ToDate =  DATEADD(day,2, @fromDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) and [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186819.aspx) Function

```
IF DATEDIFF(D,@FromDate,@ToDate)  > 2
BEGIN  
  --if it satisfies
  SET @ToDate = DATEADD(D,2, @fromDate)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove the time part from date by converting it to date like

```
 convert(date,convert(varchar,@FromDate))
 convert(date,convert(varchar,@ToDate))
```

So then you will have only date and then you can find the difference between two date using DATEDIFF sql function

Final solution

```
IF DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,convert(varchar,@FromDate)),convert(date,convert(varchar,@ToDate)))  > 2
BEGIN  
  --if it satisfies
  SET @ToDate = DATEADD(day,2, convert(date,convert(varchar,@FromDate)))
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use DateDiff
Use below query may be it helps you.

```
if( Datediff(day, Todate, FromDate) > 2)
// Your query
```